# San Francisco is my home

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

> Joseph Story
>   Mary Stuart
>   Malala Yousafzai
>   Theodore Roosevelt
>
> Bill
>   Joe
>
> red
>   army
>   pharaoh
>   bullet

note: the clues form 2 words
hint: The first and third groups should be easier and the second is a good sanity check when combined with the title.
hint: all members of the first group have a **common trait** and all members of the third group are **types of something**. The first and third group's members are not the only things/people that exhibit these characteristics, but as far as I know, there shouldn't be really anything else that tightly binds these members together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combining @jafe’s, @Matthew Barber’s, and @Gareth McCaughan’s answers, yields the two word clue

> Youngest Giant

This can be combined with

> The title, that says that San Francisco is their home, could imply the answer is **Madison Bumgarner**, the *youngest* pitcher to ever start for the *San Francisco Giants*.

Answer (score 8):

*Joseph Story

Mary Stuart

Malala Yousafzai

Theodore Roosevelt*

(Haven't figured this out yet.)

*Bill

Joe*

> can both be preceded by **G.I.**

*red

army

pharaoh

bullet*

> are all types of **ant**

so clearly

> our second word is GIANT (which fits with the title, perhaps, since there the *San Francisco Giants* are a major league baseball team).

But

> I'm drawing a blank on that first group. Mary Stuart and Malala Yousafzai were both "displaced persons", kinda; Malala Yousafzai and Theodore Roosevelt both had unsuccessful attempts made on their lives by shooting; all but Malala Yousafzai had spouses who died while they were fairly young; none of this seems likely to help. If there's any word that naturally goes before GIANT and fits the title, I've failed to think of it. (The baseball team isn't named for any feature of SF; they were the New York Giants before they were the San Francisco Giants.) They've all been characters in movies, but that doesn't seem like a special enough characteristic.

*Note*: Let the record show (as the timestamps may not always) that Matthew Barber's answer with the same answer to the third group was posted before this one. (But, also for the record, I got it independently.)

Comment: So far all correct. I kind of expected the second group to be hard, since it had only 2 clues.

Answer (score 7):

The answer for the first group is

> **youngest**
>
>  Joseph Story - youngest person to serve on the US Supreme Court
>  Mary Stuart - youngest British monarch
>  Malala Yousafzai - youngest Nobel Peace Prize winner
>  Theodore Roosevelt - youngest US president

No idea how that connects to the second word or the title, though...

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about the first two groups yet but...

> The third group are all types of ant.

Comment: I had that and the second group but am blanking on the first...